# ImageMagick do not rotate image according to EXIF

Tags: image, imagemagick, orientation, exif

[wrong exif http://gist.qiniudn.com/auto-orient-bug.jpg](http://gist.qiniudn.com/auto-orient-bug.jpg)

This image has EXIF `"Orientation":{"val":"Top-left","type":3}`, we know its EXIF is obvious wrong, but it should rotate and lay down.

I use newest ImageMagick running:

```
convert auto-orient-bug.jpg -auto-orient output.jpg
```

the output image is same as the origin.
My question is how ImageMagick dectect this and keep the image standing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in ImageMagick and will be fixed in 6.8.8-2. The bug report can be found here: http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=24749